# PDF not shown if browser downloads content automatically

Tags: bootstrap-4, lightbox, featherlight.js, featherlight

Has anyone an idea how to tackle cases where client's browser has the setting turned on to [automatically download files](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_download-actions) (instead of opening them in browser)?

In my current implementation, in such a case, the file is downloaded but the featherlight/iframe remains empty/white.

I'm triggering the featherlight simply via a button in html:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-modal" href="file.pdf" data-featherlight="iframe">
       <img class="modal-button-icon" src="icon.svg" alt="Grundriss" style=>
    </button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change `button` to an anchor `a`, and add `download` attribute to it. Look for this demo: https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute

```
<a class="btn btn-modal" href="file.pdf" download="file.pdf" data-featherlight="iframe">
       <img class="modal-button-icon" src="icon.svg" alt="Grundriss">
</a>
```

**UPDATE:** I misunderstood what you want. You can simply embed a PDF file in Bootstrap modal and show modal without Featherlight (there is a conflict between Bootstrap and Featherlight)

**IMPORTANT!!!**
PDF is not displayed in this code preview, please code the code from below to a HTML file and test it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            
            <object data="https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;">
                <embed src="https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf" type="application/pdf">
                    <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
                </embed>
            </object>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this didnt do the trick for me. 
The file still gets downloaded and the lightbox remains white/empty.